# force https on a laravel project

Tags: laravel, https

I am trying to force my laravel project to use https instead of http, and i tried everything :

i added these lines to my HTACCESS file :

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

i used AppServiceProvider :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

URL::forceScheme('https');
```

i did through the middleware too, but my URL doesn't seem to be changing anytime soon .

any idea why it isn't working !!

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-https-ssl-on-laravel/ try this

Comment: Make sure the `APP_URL` in your .env is also https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i fixed it, i didn't know there was two .htaccess files and i needed to to add the code to the one in public directory to apply the changes .

now it's working perfectly just added these lines to the htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: where did the second htaccess reside? thats an interesting question

Comment: @Flame one is in the public directory and the other one is just in the project directory where .env is

Comment: The one in the root directory shouldnt be there since it should be out of scope for direct access. i.e. you should never be able to view `www.example.com/.env` and see your env file there.

Comment: @Flame i have both my .env and .htaccess in the root directory is that a problem should i delete them ?

Comment: The `.env` needs to stay in the root. But it is important that this directory is not reachable, which means that apache/nginx should point specifically to `my_project/public`. So the only thing that is exposed is the `public/index.php`. So the `.htaccess` can be removed in the root folder (but maybe you should check what is written in it first)

Comment: @Flame by the root directory you mean the folder which the project is or the big folder where everything is, i am still confused when it comes to the server and deployment